# Extra Small Spacing

Tags: css

removed

So if you look at the tabs and look at `hw2`, you'll notice it has a little extra spacing that overlaps the spacing on the right. That's because wrapped the `div` in the `<li>`. You will notice the others not having it. I don't understand why is it making that extra little spacing after I wrap it.

Just for the record, this is for CSS spacing which has nothing to do with the JS.

**Update:** I found a ghetto work around!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up just changing the css for that page.

Answer (score 0):

Is it a space (or the absence of one)?

`display: inline` will respect whitespace.

Comment: It's definitely a space. I want to get rid of the space whitespace, so it won't overlap the gap between the tabs. In other words, i want it to show the gap between the tabs.

Comment: What did you suggest to add `display: inline` to?

Comment: No, my point is your tabs _already_ have `display: inline ` applied to them. Therefore, your source code has a space in the wrong place. As Greg mentioned, you cannot put a block-level element in an inline element, so you should change the style of the `<li/>` s to `display: inline-block`

Answer (score 0):

You are putting a block level element (div) inside an inline element (li), which is invalid. Most browsers do a reasonable job of rendering this sort of thing, but the results are unpredictable.

I would suggest using divs for the higher level menu. You could use a container div for the menu and float divs within that for the individual tabs.